# Existe algum evento socket.io que ativa quando a internet do cliente está lenta?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket, eventos, socket.io

Olá.

Estou em um projeto em nodejs + socket.io, eu estou com grande problema, em relação internet lenta do cliente, eu preciso saber se dentro socket.io existe algum evento tipo assim
// Se a internet do cliente estiver lenta ativa essa função

```
socket.event('internetLenta',function(){
  alert('Sua internet está com lentidão, poderá ocorrer delay entre você e o servidor');/
});
```

Será que existe uma forma de eu saber se a internet do cliente está lenta via socket.io?

Abraços

Comment: Não[.](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/134428/#comment278566_134428)

Comment: Só fazendo requisições com `XMLHttpRequest`... ou você pode detectar se a internet está lenta enquanto a página carrega (mas isso só dá uma vez): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994061/how-to-detect-slow-internet-connections.